# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server don't see partitions

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning

I’m Linux newbie. And have problem. And stuck.
I would like to install Linux server 18.04 LTS on HP Compaq Elite 8300 in BIOS boot but I can’t find the way. I prepared partitions in Gparted but instaler don’t see them. I check a lot of topics. Can’t find the solution. Below details.

I have prepared partitions in GParted as above:
[GParted details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jvun.png)

I turned off UEFI boot mode in BIOS and during instalation I chose legacy mode boot:
[BIOS boot setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpal1.jpg)

In BIOS is chosen AHCI mode.

18.04 LTS installer is prepared in YUMI with such options:
[YUMI options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5dVQ.jpg)

When Im using option ‘manual’ partitioning during Ubuntu installation I don’t see partitions form Gparted:
[Partitioning options in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVx2a.jpg)

I also used option "add a first partion" and after instalation check via command fdisk that the partition is GPT. I need GRUB in MBR.

Where am I making worng step?
What drives me crazy is that in version **18.04.6** installer see partitioned disk same as **20.04**..

Comment: Confirm. Its AHCI.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as to why 18.04 isn't seeing the partitions the way that 18.04.6 is.  One thing to take into consideration is that 18.04 is only supported for another 9, almost 10 months, until it goes EoL.  Looking over the [specs for your system](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-elite-8300-ultra-slim-pc/5232866/document/c03345460) I don't see any reason why you couldn't install 20.04 server.  It will be supported until 2025.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have intalled 20.04 as it was finnaly acceptable by my needs. Topic to close.